# Importing Hotmail/Yahoo/Skype contacts in C#

Tags: c#, contacts, hotmail, import

I am trying to build a social networking website of my own (like facebook). Facebook gives an option of importing contact lists from Hotmail/Yahoo/Gmail/Skype and others.

I want to implement the same functionality. I have been able to do it successfully with GMAIL, thanks to their GOOGLE DATA API which is available online. But I have been unsuccessful for hotmail, yahoo and skype. I'm wondering, does there even exist such a way of doing this? I have found many codes online that claim to do it but none of them work. I just wish to know if I'm wasting time on something that can't be done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo does provide API to import contacts. Check out the Codeproject article which might help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/yahoo-contact-reader.aspx